# How Can I Get All Rows Using IN Subquery if the Subquery Returns No Rows

Tags: oracle, subquery, where-clause

I have a query like this;

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE ID IN(
        SELECT ID FROM B WHERE STATUS=1
    )
```

I want to get all rows if sub query is null

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You Should use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.Status = 1
```

Comment: this gets just b.status=1

Comment: @hbaltuntel If you want to retrieve all means remove the condition of `status`

Comment: As I said, if subquery returns some ids, I want them. If subquery returns null, I want all in A. condition of status must be used in query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `DISTINCT` as the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON (A.ID = B.ID AND B.STATUS= 1)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The same result as from the above query can be obtained with `SELECT * FROM A` ...

Comment: But what if there are two rows for the same ID in table B? I have used `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates

Comment: Rigth, `DISTINCT`compensates possible dups caused by the `JOIN` - my point - if you remove *both* ot them you still get the same result - all rows from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *I want to get all rows if sub query* **returns no rows** 
use a three step approach

**1 Check Subquery**

```
select count(*) FROM B WHERE STATUS=1
```

If you get result > 0 the follow with step 2 otherwise with three

**2 Get Subquery Result**

```
-- your original query
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE ID IN(
        SELECT ID FROM B WHERE STATUS=1
    )
```

**3 Get All Data**

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

**Alternative One Query Approach**

Using `OR` you writes the query as you say: if the query returns no rows get all data.

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE ID IN(
        SELECT ID FROM B WHERE STATUS=1
    )
OR (SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE STATUS=1) = 0
```